# how to update data in cloud kit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a cloud kit database with 2 record types:

1. List of people
2. List of rooms

The people occupying the rooms keeps changing.  I have a `CKRecord`.Reference stored in the people record type that references one of the rooms.  However this reference needs to keep changing because the person occupying the room keep changing.

I've been struggling to update the reference without creating a new record.

I have tried to pull the `CKRecord` out of the array of `CkRecords` for the people, create a new reference to the room I would like that person to occupy and save this reference back to the person record, then save this with a `CKModifyRecordsOperation` object.

However, this seems to create a new record in my database rather than updating the current one.

```
if providerAssignedRoom == nil {
    self.roomAssignmentDelegate?.assignRoom(roomID: self.selectedRoomCKRecID, provider: provider, completion: self.transitionBackToRoot) 
}
else {
    let newProvider = self.searchCKRecArrayForProviderRef(providerRecID, self.providersCKRecsArray)
    let reference = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: 
    self.selectedRoomCKRecID, action: .none) 
    newProvider[RecordTypes.providerEnum.assignedRoom] = reference
    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record, newProvider], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    operation.completionBlock = {
        print("record reference assigned to nil")
    }
    LaborFloorNamesDB.share.publicDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply to add a save policy.  I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.

```
let providerToBeAssigned = self.providersArray[indexPath.item]
let providerToBeAssignedCKRef = self.findProviderCKRecordBasedOnProviderObject(provider: providerToBeAssigned)

var roomToBeReferenced: CKRecord {
    let object = self.roomsAsCKRecsArray.filter {$0.recordID == self.selectedRoomCKRecID}
    let value = object.first
    return value!
}

if self.providerToBeRemoved != nil {
    self.providerToBeRemoved![RecordTypes.providerEnum.assignedRoom] = nil
}

providerToBeAssignedCKRef![RecordTypes.providerEnum.assignedRoom] = CKRecord.Reference(record: roomToBeReferenced, action: .none)

let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [providerToBeAssignedCKRef!, self.providerToBeRemoved!], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
operation.savePolicy = .changedKeys
operation.completionBlock = {
    print("record reference updated to cloud")
}

LaborFloorNamesDB.share.publicDatabase.add(operation)
```